# A code to find out the count of females and males in a column using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want an output in a table as shown below:

```
 GENDER    SUM
   Male    432
 Female    521
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example inspired by [this article](https://datascienceparichay.com/article/pandas-count-of-unique-values-in-each-column/)

```
import pandas as pd

# create a sample dataframe
data = {
    'A': ['E1', 'E2', 'E3', 'E4', 'E5'],
    'B': ['Male', 'Female', 'Female', 'Male', 'Male'],
    'C': [27, 24, 29, 24, 25],
    'D': ['Accounting', 'Sales', 'Accounting', 'Coding', 'Sales']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df['Gender'].value_counts()) # This is what you will use
```

This prints

```
Male      3
Female    2
Name: Gender, dtype: int64
```

You can read more about `value_counts()` [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html).

Comment: Actually I want to import the data from a cav file and do the sum operation..

Comment: After this output(sum) I want to plot a bar diagram ( gender vs sum/total num)

Comment: Hi @Ash - I think that those are sufficiently different to warrant putting them into separate questions - if you link those here I'd be happy to answer them for your specific use case. Alternatively, see relevant questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29026664/11771447) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65282011/11771447), respectively.